# CMD/Batch: Copying files with symbols in path

Tags: batch-file, cmd

What's the best way to deal with symbols like "Registered" in a file path - besides renaming?

I have a folder "Name®_Name®_1500" that I am trying to copy a file into. When I try to select the folder with wildcard it reads like "Namer_Namer_1500" which obviously isn't a real folder. And If I echo the path back it shows "Name«_Name«_1500".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the short name of the path. try dir /x to get the short name :

```
C:\temp>dir /x name*

26/04/2013  22:59    <REP>          NAME_N~1     Name®_Name®_1500

C:\temp>copy log.txt .\NAME_N~1
        1 fichier(s) copié(s).
```

Comment: Annotation: ShortNames will not be avaliable if they are disabled in the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct CodePage.

**Example:**

```
@Echo OFF

CHCP 1252 1>NUL
MKDIR "Name®_Name®_1500ºªçÇñÑ" 2>NUL

CHCP 850 1>NUL
Dir /B /AD "Name*"

CHCP 1252 1>NUL
CD /D "Name®_Name®_1500ºªçÇñÑ"

CHCP 850 1>NUL
Echo: You are inside "%CD%"

Pause&Exit
```

**Note:** Save that script with ANSI encoding.

**Output:**

```
Name®_Name®_1500ºªçÇñÑ
You are inside "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Name®_Name®_1500ºªçÇñÑ"
```